# cellTemplate для angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Мне нужно чтобы в ячейке одной из колонок (по условию если IsEnum = true) был select dropdown.

Я делаю так:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data.forEach(function (dataItem) {
    var columnDef = {};
    columnDef.cellTemplate = '<div ng-if="row.entity.IsEnum" style="padding: 2px 5px;text-align:center;"><select style="width:100%;height:28px;border-radius:3px;" ng-model="selectedEnumItem" ng-options="item.Name for item in dicEnumItems"></select></div>';
    columnDef.field = 'Value';
    columnDef.displayName = 'Значение';
    ...
    if(dataItem.IsEnum){
        referenceService.getDicEnum($scope.userId, dataItem.TypeName).then(function (dicEnums) {
          $scope.dicEnumItems = dicEnums.data;
        });
    }
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push(columnDef);
}
```

В итоге в dicEnumItems записывается массив. Но dropdown почему-то пустой.

Ссылка на Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EDE7UBb07upwIQFzj5WG?p=preview

Comment: сможешь сделать пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)? Почти уверен, что проблема с isolate scope и скорее всего поможет какой-нибудь `in $parent.dicEnumItems` Но проверить негде :-)

Comment: Не могу создать пока-что. В консоли куча ошибок валиться. Основное я написал. Может быть потому-что `getDicEnum` работает асинхронно, и на момент добавления `columnDef` массив `$scope.dicEnumItems` еще пустой? Но тогда не понятно как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Пример должен быть **минимальным**, не надо переносить весь проект.

Comment: в консоли пишет Failed to instantiate module ui.grid. Элементарно не могу подключить модуль ui.grid. Вот ссылка, если интересно: https://plnkr.co/edit/EDE7UBb07upwIQFzj5WG?p=preview

Comment: Где ссылка-то? Можешь ее в вопрос тоже добавить

Comment: как где в комментарии, выше в вопрос сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51874/discussion-between-grundy-and-endovitskiiy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение, если кому-то понадобиться: https://plnkr.co/edit/U81BqnUPKzr3q7ngqszv?p=preview

Это главное:

```
ng-options="item.Name for item in row.entity.dicEnumItems"
```

Добавление `dicEnumItems` в `row.entity`:

```
if (dataItem.IsEnum) {
      dataItem.dicEnumItems = $scope.getDicEnum();
  }
```

`dataItem` - это и есть row.entity.

Comment: допиши как ты добавил _dicEnumItems_ в _entity_, хотя бы словами